# IDE with AutoCompletion?

Tags: editors, auto-completion, ide

I was looking for an Latex editor that has an auto completion function. Is there any available?

I thought about auto complete suggestion for common commands like for example defining chapters and sections etc.

Comment: TeXworks, Kile, WinEdt, VIM, Emacs and many others.

Comment: [List of LaTeX IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/215)

Comment: @Leo Editting any file not with vim would be a pain. How does vim achieve the autocompletion?

Comment: @Thanks for all the answers. I realized now that I should have asked how does autocompletion work in TexWorks ad not which IDE supports autocompletion.

Comment: For mathematical formula auto-complete in Tex, you can use https://www.mathcha.io Its an online editor and easy to use for folks who dont understand much Math Tex

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a [list of LaTeX IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/215)

While [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)+[AucTeX](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/) doesn't have "autocompletion" *per se* but it does have something that performs the same role, and performs it better (obviously).

Let's take the example of adding section headings. With autocompletion I start writing `\sec...` and then press <kbd>TAB</kbd> or some such autocomplete key.

With emacs, you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and emacs asks you what level of sectioning you want. You type `sec...` and then <kbd>TAB</kbd> to autocomplete. Then emacs asks you how you'd like to label that section (I want to call this section `foo`). It automatically adds a `\label{sec:foo}` below your `\section` command.

Fine. But here's the really useful part. Let's say you want an environment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. Then emacs asks you what kind of environment you want. And if you tell it you want an environment emacs understands, like `minipage` it will ask you for its compulsory arguments (width, for minipage). It will then create the environment and put you between the `\begin` and `\end` tags.

More cool features of emacs: [`abbrev-mode`](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/emacs18/emacs_27.html) which is basically auto-complete on magic!

And the smart <kbd>`</kbd> : Typing <kbd>`</kbd> then <kbd>a</kbd> gives you `\alpha` likewise for other greek letters. <kbd>`</kbd> then pressing the right arrow key gives you `\rightarrow` Likewise for other arrow directions...

Also, you get like, 100 geek points just for using emacs. Fact.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that emacs's `abbrev mode` (ie. autocompletion) will complete _any_ word, not just LaTeX macros, which is very handy if you use a lot of long words.  Its sibling, `dabbrev mode`, can automatically fix typos like "teh" and do other useful and fully automatic text replacement.

Comment: @Ross Thats a good point. I don't use abbrev mode much myself...

Comment: in emacs [Ctrl+c] then [Ctrl+m] will prompt you for the name of a macro, hit tab, and it will autocomplete (in the minibuffer). There is probably a way to add this directly to the [tab] key after typing `\`.

Comment: It's not nearly as well-developed as AucTeX, but Ultra-TeX mode for Emacs does autocompletion: hit the backslash key, and it starts completing on TeX commands, using a list constructed by the user (although Ultra-TeX comes with a starter list) and also from "newcommands", etc., in the current document.

Answer (score 5):

TeXworks has some builtin autocompletion, but take a look at the script [autocompleteForTexworks](https://raw.github.com/henrikmidtiby/autocompleteForTexworks/master/scripts/autocomplete.js). The script can perform completion on long words earlier used in your document, labels and filenames for `\input`, `\include` and `\includegraphics` macros.

There is a video of it in action on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRSq_OSxPec).

Guide to use.

1. start typing the long word that should be autocompleted
2. press <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> and the autocompleter will complete the word or at least make a suggestion for a completion.
3. if not satisfied with the suggestion press <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> until the correct word is found.

Disclaimer: I'm author of the autocomplete script.

Comment: I can't use the scripts. I copied the files based on the instruction, but as I hit the Reload button, it does not recognize the two JS files. Any idea why? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

TexnicCenter in windows also has a completion function with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> and additional custom commands can be added in xml files in the TexnicCenter program folder

Answer (score 3):

You did not specify your OS, but if you're running GNU/Linux, you should have a look at [Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/), which does that to some extent. [Here's a screenshot illustrating that feature](http://kile.sourceforge.net/showscreenshot.php?id=2).

Comment: Kile theoretically can be compiled and run on Windows as well.

Comment: "To some extent"? Kile is amazing in that it even recognizes macros I defined myself and knows how many parameters they take. ... sometimes at least, so ... yeah, maybe "to some extent" was accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Multiplatform TeXworks has autocomplete (using <kbd>tab</kbd>). Texmaker and TeXlipse (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>) have it and are multiplatform as well. I am hard pressed to think of any that do not offer it.

Answer (score 0):

[Atom](https://atom.io/) is a text editor that can be extended with packages. People have made a wide range of these, giving you latex compilation, syntax highlighting, autocompletion and practically anything else that might be useful.

Plus, if it doesn't exist already, there's always the option to write the package yourself. You can then publish it, so everyone can access it.

**Edit**: I wrote an [autocomplete package](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-latex) for it. It's highly customisable, and suggestions for features / improvements are welcome.